# WPF set CaretPosition at start of a RichTextBox

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, caret

I have a `RichTextBox` in my WPF app, filled with colored text.
I want to make it programmatically go to the start of the document, so I followed msdn's recommandation:

```
    TextPointer caretPos = RTB.CaretPosition;
    caretPos = caretPos.DocumentStart;
    RTB.CaretPosition = caretPos;
```

And that does precisely nothing...

I also tried:

```
RTB.Selection.Select(RTB.Document.ContentStart, RTB.Document.ContentStart);
```

Which didn't work either.

I couldn't find other information on the subject aside from another question in StackOVerflow, that remains unanswered.

Anyone has a solution?

Comment: Simple solution, don't touch the Caret! RTB.ScrollToHome(); did the deed.

Comment: Don't post this as a comment, post it as an answer and mark it as such.

Comment: I can't post solutions to my own problems =/

Comment: What is preventing you from doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution, don't touch the Caret! RTB.ScrollToHome(); did the deed.

Answer (score 4):

I thought it would be this:

```
rtb.CaretPosition = rtb.Document.ContentStart;
```

Seems to work for me.